# /<CREATIVE_ID>/previews iframe autogrow

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

We use the facebook ad previews endpoint as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/generatepreview/v8.0

The endpoint returns a snippet of HTML with consisting of an IFRAME whose URL is pre-loaded to point to their marketing CDN.  The previews for the ads are then rendered inside that IFRAME.

Sometimes the preview comes back larger in height than the frame itself.  this is causing an ugly scrollbar to appear in the middle of our page.

We're trying to figure out if there's anyway to detect the height on the frame contents and adjust the iframe's height, OR is there a way to set the iframe to autogrow.  Right now we're stuck in the time-old cross-domain problem and we can't query inside the iframe with javascript.

Just wondering if anyone has had any luck with this?  Maybe an undocumented feature or a cool XD hack?

TIA

DW

Comment: Are you providing the `ad_format` param also in the API call?

Comment: I am.  The problem manifests mainly when the preview includes a "see more" link in the ad message.  So if someone clicks that in the preview then suddenly the frame is shorter than the content and thus the scrollbar appears.

I have tried to play with the height parameter before calling the endpoint but the page layout I'm confined to doesn't allow me to use a height of (say) 2000px and just handle all outcomes.  That's why being able to autogrow that frame is so important.